# How to set a single div to any of the hovered link in another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following div will is to show these 3 languages one after other in a horizontal line, like    English  Spanish  French

```
<div>
  <ul style="display:inline;">
    <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the following div to be floating below English, when user hovers his mouse on English. But if user moves to French, then this div has to be below French. 
The catch is, I cannot have the following div within the above div.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Sports</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

How to do that?
I tried few solutions, but none worked.

Comment: get position of hovered element and adjust the positon of the div

Comment: But doesn't the position vary based on the screen size?

Comment: Are there any other restrictions? E.g. can I add an ID or class to either or both divs?

Comment: @ecg8 No other restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport. [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Now you have the position of the selected element.

Going further you get the height of the element to float and add that height to the hovered element to make space for it.

```js
const x = document.querySelector('#lol')
const y = document.querySelectorAll('.li')

y.forEach(li => li.addEventListener('mouseover', float, false))
y.forEach(li => li.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeFloat, false))

function float(e) {
 if(e.target.tagName !== 'LI') return
  
 const foo = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  e.target.style.marginBottom = x.offsetHeight + 'px'

  x.style.top = foo.bottom + 'px'
}

function removeFloat(e) {
 if(e.target.tagName !== 'LI') return
  
  e.target.style.marginBottom = 0
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul style="display:inline;">
    <li class="li">
      <a href="#">English</a>
     </li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">French</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute;" id="lol">
  <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Sports</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```